# What is 0650// in the metar?

Tags: metar

I have this metar, I cannot find anywhere what does `0650//` or `1600//` or `0250//` mean. I tested on multiple decoder websites. They call it unknown identifier.

`ESCF 240220Z AUTO 00000KT 0800 0650// R01/P2000N R19/1900U BR OVC035/// 00/00 Q1005`

`ESCF 240250Z AUTO 10001KT 4100 1600// BR OVC033/// 01/01 Q1005`

`ESCF 240120Z AUTO 00000KT 0450 0250// BR OVC037/// 00/00 Q1005`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely the minimum visibility (in metres), with the compass direction given as "//" (not possible to determine). A single slash is more common, i.e. `0650/`. [WMO Publication No. 306 - Manual On Codes - Volume I.1 - Part A](http://www.wmo.int/pages/prog/www/WMOCodes/WMO306_vI1/VolumeI.1.html), Section A, FM 15 METAR, FM 16 SPECI (emphasis added):

> 15.6 Groups VVVV V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>D<sub>v</sub>
>
> 15.6.1 The group VVVV shall be used to report prevailing visibility.
>   ...
>
> 15.6.2 Directional variation in visibility 
>   V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>D<sub>v</sub>
>
> When the horizontal visibility is not the same in different directions and when the minimum visibility is different from the prevailing visibility, and less than 1,500 metres or less than 50% of the prevailing visibility, and less than 5,000 metres, the group V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>V<sub>N</sub>D<sub>v</sub> shall also be used to report **the minimum visibility and, when possible, its general direction** in relation to the aerodrome reference point indicated by reference to one of the eight points of the compass. If the minimum visibility is observed in more than one direction, the D<sub>v</sub> shall represent the most operationally significant direction.

Comment: TLDR: 0650/ should have been 0650//. `0650` is 650 meters minimum visibility and `//` is Direction not available.